# How to restrict contacts that can be assigned to an activity?

Tags: activities

Two of my clients would like to be able to restrict the contacts that can be assigned to an activity.  This is because they handle highly sensitive information and it would be potentially disastrous for them to accidentally select the wrong contact (e.g. a client rather than a case worker).  This was asked before [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/restrict-contacts-available-to-be-assigned-to-an-activity) and the question was rated a 5 - the answer from Coleman was to make a code change. I think there's a good case to build some kind of configurable restriction into core. So I'm asking this question again to see how much support there is for a core update, or alternatively to see if anyone has a better idea.

Comment: What CMS? Asking, as i did on the other ticket, because Drupal already offers this via webform_civicrm

Comment: actually if you are really asking the same question again then you may find this gets deleted as a Duplicate and you would do better to engage on the original one

Comment: The problem is that the original answer isn't satisfactory - so all I can do there is add a comment which will have less visibility. A weakness of this Q&A approach, I guess, and where the old forum worked better.

Comment: There's usually not much appetite to put something in core if it can be easily done with an extension.  The basic mechanism exists via a hook (see other answer) so it needs a configuration screen to determine which activity contacts need to be restricted.  Sounds like a fairly straightforward extension.  Commissions welcome :-)

Comment: Understood re the Q+A format. If you tweak your question to more clearly differentiate it then happy to remove the duplicate flag. But also worth making a comment on the other one since that has eyeballs on it. The fact 5 folk have given Coleman's answer a +1 doesn't mean much more than 5 folk saw that he had made an effort to respond in an informative way and no other Answers had been offered to compare with.